# Has any implementation succeeded to have shared key inside chipset and protect it from exploits?

Tags: semiconductors, packages, security, encryption, microscope

Since there is a lot of demonstration like [using SEM (Scanning Electron Microscope) to read bits from ROM through the scanned image of chipset](https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/handle/1810/261926), is there any implementation that has managed to succeed to protect its key value from physical exploitation? (by device technology, package materials, etc.)

For example, I have not find SEM or other microscope exploitation attempts against FRAM/STT-MRAM. Also, I have heard that there are some ways to prevent electrons/photons from microscope with top-layer package material, or trigger self destruction through material or on-die OTP device, but I haven't been able to find the source.

Also, [NIST FIPS 140-2](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/140/2/final) mentions Level-3/4 crypto modules should flush its key when detecting physical exploitation attempt. But is there a implementation that is ever managed to acquire Level 3 or 4 with factory-determined key?

Comment: Don't fall for Fujitsu's marketing material. Electron microscopes can see magnetism: https://www.ornl.gov/news/new-electron-microscope-method-detects-atomic-scale-magnetism

Comment: What man creates, man can hack. Why do you use the term ‘chipset’ when you seem to refer to a singular chip?

Comment: @Kartman Since I was thinking with SoC VLSI implementation with thoughts for hided interposers.